# Clicking Duo Push button with Selenium in Powershell

Tags: powershell, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, multi-factor-authentication

I am trying to use Powershell and Selenium to log into a web page protected by Duo two-factor authentication. I need to click the button so that Duo will send a push request to a mobile phone, before the site login will complete.

Inspecting the login page, I see HTML that looks like this (the button is in an iframe that I can select by id):

```
<button tabindex="2" type="submit" class="auth-button positive"><!-- -->Send Me a Push </button>
```

I cannot figure out how to click the button. I tried:

```
$chromedriver.FindElementById("duo_iframe").FindElementByXPath("//button[@type='submit']")
$chromedriver.FindElementById("duo_iframe").FindElementByClassName('auth-button')
$chromedriver.FindElementByXPath("//button[@type='submit']")
$chromedriver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@type='submit']")
$chromedriver.FindElementByCssSelector('.auth-button positive')
$chromedriver.FindElementByCssSelector('auth-button positive')
$chromedriver.FindElementByClassName('auth-button positive')
```

They all give me "element not found" errors, except the last one, which says, "Compound class names not allowed. Cannot have whitespace in class name. Use CSS selectors instead."

Any thoughts on how I can finish this login?

Comment: You need to switch to the iframe in order to locate elements inside. I don't know powershell so I'm not sure on the syntax to do that, but I'm pretty sure that's what you are missing.

Comment: I think that's what I'm doing in the first two examples. Do I need to do a "click" on the iframe?

Comment: No, you need to use the function to switch frames. in C# it is like `driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.Id("duo_iframe")));`; I looked for documentation on this related to powershell but didn't find anything

Comment: Ah, that was the thing. `$chromedriver.SwitchTo().Frame($chromedriver.FindElementById("duo_iframe"))` and 
`$chromedriver.FindElementByXPath("//button[@type='submit']").Click()` allowed me to move to the next step. Thanks.